# Explain the Open-E technology stack

Tags: storage, hardware

I wonder how the Open-E stack is built. I was not able find this information [on their website](http://www.open-e.com) or on other sites.

Is it an application that is installed on top of Linux or BSD or does it run on bare metal? Are they using publically available drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some reading on it, I found a document that describes how to log into "[the linux console](http://www.kb.open-e.com/How-do-I-mount-NFS-shares-under-the-Linux-console_95.html)". This strongly suggests that the foundation for this product is some kind of Linux, very probably heavily modified. This is not something you layer on top of an existing Linux build, though. This is something you install as a stand-alone product on bare metal. It is possible that it would work in a VM, but I don't really see the benefits of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

It's described as a "storage OS", and the system requirements only talks about hardware, not any already-installed OS; I think it's safe to assume it runs on bare metal.

Answer (score 2):

As Massimo states it's bare-metal. The manual showing this is only a couple of clicks from your link (products, dss lite, manual).